# Python Flask doesn't remember user and doesn't process user_loader

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I'm doing API authorization and ran into a problem that during authorization the user is saved only on the "login" page, but on other pages the user is displayed as anonymous. At the same time, it is not visible that @login_manager.user_loader worked (set prints for verification)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_secret'

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

# TODO: User authorization with flask
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = User.get(int(user_id))
    print("method: load_user\nmessage: ", user)
    return user

# TODO: Check FLask authorization
@app.route('/api/LogCheck/', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def log_check():
    return f"{str(current_user)}\n", 200

# TODO: User Flask login on REST API
@app.route('/api/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.json.get('username')
        password = request.json.get('password')
        
        # TODO: Get correct user password by username
        
        table_data = []
        
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_requests.get_user(username))
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error":e}), 500
        
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for row in data:
                user_id, name, telephone_number, email, subscription, first_usage, last_usage, web_password = row
                table_data.append({
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "name": name,
                    "telephone_number": telephone_number,
                    "email": email,
                    "subscription": subscription,
                    "first_usage": first_usage,
                    "last_usage": last_usage,
                    "web_password": web_password
                })
        
        print({"method":"/api/login/",
                "data": table_data[0]})
        correct_password = table_data[0]['web_password']
        
        # TODO: Check that user password is correct
        if check_password_hash(correct_password, password):
            user = User(table_data[0]['user_id'], table_data[0]['name'], table_data[0]['web_password'])
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return jsonify({"status": "success","user":str(current_user)}), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({"status": "denied"}), 401
```

```
class User():
    
    def __init__(self, id, username, password) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
        
    def get(user_id):
        
        # TODO: Connect to postgres database
        
        DB_PASS = ""
        DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
        
        connect = psycopg2.connect(
            f"dbname=database user=User password={DB_PASS} host={DB_HOST} port=5432"
        )
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        
        # TODO: return User object
        table_data = []
    
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_requests.get_user_by_id(user_id))
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error":e}), 500
    
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    
        for row in data:
            user_id, name, telephone_number, email, subscription, first_usage, last_usage, web_password = row
            table_data.append({
                "user_id": user_id,
                "name": name,
                "telephone_number": telephone_number,
                "email": email,
                "subscription": subscription,
                "first_usage": first_usage,
                "last_usage": last_usage,
                "web_password": web_password
            })
        connect.close()
        return User(table_data[0]['user_id'], table_data[0]['name'], table_data[0]['web_password'])
```

I tried changing session settings and login_manager settings. Initially, the User class inherited from UserMixin, but the result was always the same